# Problem or bug in xticklabel_rotate while drawing heatmap and rotating xtick labels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, label, rotation, heatmap

I have been drawing heatmaps with labels in Matlab, mainly using the functions **imagesc** to draw the heatmap and **xticklabel_rotate** to rotate the xtick labels. 
([please see here for xticklabel_rotate](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel_rotate)).
It usually works well. But today I met some problem which appeared to be caused by xticklabel_rotate (or maybe the Matlab *text* handle used by xticklabel_rotate?)

To illustrate the problem, in the following I print my code and the results generated from the code (basically, what it does is to randomly generate a normally distributed data matrix, draw a heatmap for the data using imagesc, draw its labels on top and right of the axis, and then rotate xticklabels):

```
function debug_xticklabelRotate(numX, numY, axisFontsize)
    data = randn(numY, numX);
    imagesc(data);
    colormap(jet);
    box on
    set(gca, 'ticklength', [0,0]);
    set(gca, 'xminortick', 'off', 'yminortick', 'off');
    set(gca, 'XAxisLocation', 'top');
    set(gca, 'YAxisLocation', 'right');
    set(gca,'FontSize', axisFontsize);
    axis image
    set(gca, 'Xtick', 1 : numX);
    htext = xticklabel_rotate([],90, [], 'fontsize', axisFontsize);
    set(gca, 'YTick', 1 : numY);
end
```

**Problem 1**: I called the above function with parameters as

```
debug_xticklabelRotate(40, 100, .5);
```

the output image is shown below (to save space here, I cut the image and only show the top few rows):

[image]

Please notice that the bug is that, as the result of calling xticklabel_rotate, neither the right side of the figure box nor the yticklabels are drawn.

**Problem 2**: When I call the above function with parameters as

```
debug_xticklabelRotate(40, 200, .5);  % only numY is changed from 100 to 200
```

the output image is shown below (again to save space here, I cut the image and only show the top few rows):

http://i55.tinypic.com/317grdd.png

Compared to the call with numY=100, in this figure both the data image and the labels are shown. However, please notice two problems here. First, the **fontsize** of xticklabel is not the same as that of yticklabel (axisFontsize). Second, the xtick labels are **not aligned** well with the columns (xticks): some labels are closer and some are further away.

Please note if I remove the function call of xticklable_rotate in my function debug_xticklabelRotate, all these mentioned problems are gone (except that now the xticklabel are not rotated).

I wish my problem is stated clear above. Any suggestion on solving the problem will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of `xticklabel_rotate`, I have tried to reproduce the errors mentioned with only small success. I have found an issue with the axis position being changed when y-labels are on the right, which I will look into. I do not get such marked misalignements as you have shown when I run the same examples, so I am not sure how to respond. Please verify that these issues exist when you PRINT the figure, and it is not a simple display issue.

The text boxes are created at the tick positions, in data units. They are middle aligned, there is not much more that can be done, but I am open to suggestions.

PS. I agree it would be nice if this function was inherent in MatLab. If it was, I wouldn't have had to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the line:

```
set(gca, 'YAxisLocation', 'right')
```

then it should work as expected. It seems that the XTICKLABEL_ROTATE function does not support right y-labels. You should contact the original author and let him know of the possible bug...

Comment: Hi Amro: the two issues(fontsize and alignment) described in Problem 2 exists for both left y-label and right y-label.  Use left y-label in debug_xticklabelRotate(40, 100, .5) does produce a heatmap with data, box and labels all displayed, though as in the second image, the fontsize and alignment issues described in Problem 2 still appear. xticklabel_rotate has been a very popular and appreciated function, but there are some other issues besides the one I mentioned here. Not sure if there are alternatives to it or why Matlab does not provide a built in support for rotation.